# Redraw canvas using localStorage object in FabricJs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

My canvas id is "canvas-panel" I want to redraw my canvas using the localStorage object value when go to the next page. I am getting canvas object using localStorage object like below:

```
var myCanvas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('canvas'));
```

JSON formate:

```
{
"objects":[

  {
     "type":"image",
     "originX":"left",
     "originY":"top",
     "left":42,
     "top":311,
     "width":100,
     "height":100,
     "fill":"rgb(0,0,0)",
     "stroke":null,
     "strokeWidth":1,
     "strokeDashArray":null,
     "strokeLineCap":"butt",
     "strokeLineJoin":"miter",
     "strokeMiterLimit":10,
     "scaleX":1,
     "scaleY":1,
     "angle":0,
     "flipX":false,
     "flipY":false,
     "opacity":1,
     "shadow":null,
     "visible":true,
     "clipTo":null,
     "backgroundColor":"",
     "fillRule":"nonzero",
     "globalCompositeOperation":"source-over",
     "src":"http://stg.souqueen.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/300x300/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/9/19b_1024i1.PNG",
     "filters":[

     ],
     "crossOrigin":"",
     "alignX":"none",
     "alignY":"none",
     "meetOrSlice":"meet"
  }
],
"background":""
}
```

I am getting all canvas object with the help of this thread
[Select All the objects on canvas using Fabric.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593163/select-all-the-objects-on-canvas-using-fabric-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got your json. So now on next page you can import the objects using  this :

`canvas.loadFromJSON(myCanvas, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas))`

Comment: It is loading in new canvas but not modifying existing canvas am i doing something wrong?

Comment: check the `canvas` you are using. It may be the issue.